# PHP echo username after login

Tags: php, html

I am trying to echo the username of user when they are signed in but the code I have isn't doing anything . I am also not getting any errors . I've changed a few things around but nothing changed . Can someone please help me ?

```
<?php

include("connect.php"); 

if(isset($_POST['usernam'])) {

$usernam = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['usernam']);
if(ctype_alnum($usernam)){

    $check = mysqli_query("SELECT usernam FROM users WHERE usernam='$usernam'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check)==1){

        $get = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
        $usernam = $get['usernam'];
    } else {
        echo"user does not exists";
    }
}

?>

<center><h2><?php echo $usernam;?></h2></center>
```

index.php :

```
<form action="process2.php" method="post">
<p id="p2"><input type="usernam" size="25" name="username" placeholder="Username" ><p />
<p><input type="password" size="25" name="pw" placeholder="Password" ><p />
<p id="p3"><a href="forgotpass.php">Forgot Password ?</a></p>

<button id="bt2" type="submit" name="signin">Login</button>

</form>
```

process2.php(login code)

```
<?php

include("connect.php");

//check if form is submitted
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' || 
! isset($_POST['signin'])) 
{
// looks like a hack, send to index.php
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
}

if (empty($_POST["usernam"])) {
echo 'fill in username to sign in .  ';
}
if (empty($_POST["pw"])) {
echo 'fill in password to sign in .  ';
}

$sql = "SELECT pw FROM users WHERE usernam = ?";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
if ( !$stmt ) {
echo mysqli_error($conn);
exit;
}

$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['pw']);
$stmt->execute();

if ( !$stmt ) {
echo mysqli_error($conn);
exit;
}
// we found a row with that username, 
// now we need to check the password is correct

// get the password from the row
$stmt->bind_result($hashed_pwd);
$stmt->fetch();

if ( password_verify($_POST['pw'], $hashed_pwd) ) {
// password verified
    header('Location: home.php');
} else {
echo 'Incorrect username or Password. <a href= index.php>Try again</a><br />';
}
?>
```

connect.php:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "passxx";
$dbname = "interpage";
$msqli_query = ("SELECT * FROM users");

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if($conn == true) {
}

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133145/discussion-on-question-by-user7327480-php-echo-username-after-login).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: you have to click on the `Login Button` in your `index.php` file to be able to login. Otherwise if you just type the `process2.php` in the address bar, you WILL NOT get logged in, because username and password will be empty...**

You have few problems and errors in your code:

1- in you index.php, there is not a `type="usernam"` in html, you have to use `type="text"`

So your **index.php** will be like this:

```
<form action="process2.php" method="post">
    <p id="p2"><input type="text" size="25" name="username" placeholder="Username" ><p />
    <p><input type="password" size="25" name="pw" placeholder="Password" ><p />
    <p id="p3"><a href="forgotpass.php">Forgot Password ?</a></p>
    <button id="bt2" type="submit" name="signin">Login</button>
</form>
```

2- Now in your **process2.php** file, because in your form then name of the username element was `name="username"` So here we have to use `$_POST["username"]` instead of `$_POST["usernam"]`.

Then I think after checking `if (empty($_POST["username"])) {` and `if (empty($_POST["pw"])) {`, you should not continue to the rest of your code. Because username or password were empty, So we will add a `die();` and a link to `index.php` page in these `if statements`

At this line `$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['pw']);` you should bind `username` to the query, not the `password` so I change it to `$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);`

At these two lines

```
$stmt->execute();
if ( !$stmt ) {
```

We should change it to `if ( $stmt->execute() ) {`

I'm also replacing all the `exit;` with `die();` which is more appropriate to use.

Also note that in your process2.php file, sometimes you are using mysqli `Object oriented style` and some other times `Procedural style`. It's not correct and try to choose one of these methods and stick to it...

The rest of the code seems OK.

**UPDATE**

To use your username in other pages after login, you have to use `session`. For this, you have to put this line `session_start();` at the top of all the pages you want to use session(you can put it at the top of any file that is including on beginning of all of you files, like your `connect.php` file)

Then you can use `$_SESSION` superglobal variable to store/read data in/from it in different pages like this:

you can use this like `$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];` to store the posted username in the `$_SESSION['username']` in `process2.php` file and then use `echo $_SESSION['username'];` to show the stored username in your other files like your `home.php` file.

So your **process2.php** will be like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("connect.php");

//check if form is submitted
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' || ! isset($_POST['signin'])) 
{
    // looks like a hack, send to index.php
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}

if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
    echo 'fill in username to sign in. <a href= index.php>Try again</a><br />';
    die();
}

if (empty($_POST["pw"])) {
    echo 'fill in password to sign in. <a href= index.php>Try again</a><br />';
    die();
}

$sql = "SELECT pw FROM users WHERE usernam = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
if ( !$stmt ) {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    die();
}

$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
if ( !$stmt->execute() ) {
    echo mysqli_error($conn);
    die();
}
// we found a row with that username, 
// now we need to check the password is correct

// get the password from the row
$stmt->bind_result($hashed_pwd);
$stmt->fetch();

if ( password_verify($_POST['pw'], $hashed_pwd) ) {
    // password verified
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    header('Location: home.php');
} else {
    echo 'Incorrect username or Password. <a href= index.php>Try again</a><br />';
}
?>
```

And then in your **home.php** file or any other file you want to show username, you can easily use:

```
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

To show the username which was used to log in...

And then for **logout** you have to clear the session, So you have to put these lines in your logout file:

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
$_SESSION = array();
session_regenerate_id(true);
```